# A different version of weighted interval scheduling

Tags: algorithms

Assume that $n$ customers want to buy icecream from $1$ shop. The icecreams are not identical. It takes $t_i$ time for the shopkeeper to make icecream #$i$.

This shopkeeper keeps a weight for each customer in his mind. So, each customer $j$ has a weight of $w_j$ in the shopkeeper's mind.

The shopkeeper wants to schedule the time to maximize the general satisfaction. But he also  wants to satisfy the ones with more weights more than the others.

He represents the schedule in this way: $C_i$ is the finishing time for the prepration of the icecream which the $i$'th person wants.  So, if customer #$j$ is the first customer that the shopkeeper prepares the icecream for him, and customer #$j$ is the second one, We have $C_j=t_j$ and $C_i=t_i+t_j$.

The objective function is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i c_i$. We want to minimize it.

How can we provide a schedule for this shopkeeper to fulfill his interests?

Any Hint or Solution will be appreciated.

**Please keep in mind that i want algorithm. Not just a modeling for an optimization problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal strategy is to just sort the customers by the value of the fraction $\frac{t_i}{w_i}$.

If you don't do this, then your ordering has two adjacent customers $i$ and $j$ such that $\frac{t_i}{w_i} > \frac{t_j}{w_j}$ but you serve customer $i$ before customer $j$. Let $T$ be the total time spent on customers before this pair. Then these two customers contribute a total of $w_i(T + t_i) + w_j(T + t_i + t_j)$ to the objective function.

If we were to switch the two customers, they'd contribute $w_j (T + t_j) + w_i(T + t_i + t_j)$ instead, for a change of $w_i t_j - w_j t_i < 0$, without affecting  the objective function in any other way. So the ordering is not optimal.

So the only correct solution is to sort by $\frac{t_i}{w_i}$.

Comment: What should i do after sorting?!

Comment: After sorting, that's your schedule.